# Custom search bar modification in Shopify

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, html-helper

I was making a medicine store on Shopify and I have two issues:

1. want to make the search bar appear only when the user has signed up,
2. also I cannot show all products available, I only have to show the medicines the user has searched and knows the name of.

Comment: How do you know a prior users know the name of medicine?

Comment: Through the prescription given by the doctor.